# Create a trigger function in Postgres that doesn't let you have two entries with the same id

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have two tables in postgres, 
I want to create a function that doesn’t have more than 2 loans in the lending table with the same person id.
example: in the loan table I cannot have 3 loans that are from the same person, that is, we loan with the same person's id.

I need to do this using a function, I put what I was trying to do but it didn't work

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    name_person varchar (100) ,
    id_person varchar(14) primary key
)

CREATE TABLE lending(
    id_lending primary key (100) ,
    id_publication (14) FK,
    id_person fk REFERENCES id_person (person)




CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_numlending() 
RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$ 
BEGIN 
IF( select * from lending
   inner join person 
   on person.id_person = lending.id_person > 2  ) THEN 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR'; 
END IF; 
RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql; 


-- Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER  
trg_check_num_lending  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON 
lendingFOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_numlending();
```

Comment: What is `NEW.id_person = person.id_person > 2` supposed to do? If you want to verify some condition on the existing table data, you need to execute a `SELECT` inside the function

Comment: hello, I fixed this part, what I want is almost that ... but how do I check if there is more than twice the id_person in the lending table?

Comment: Well, if you want to learn how many rows there are in a query result, you typically use `SELECT COUNT(*)`... You would be well advised to learn the basics of SQL first; otherwise, you're going to have a hard time writing DB procedures and functions

Comment: I got it now, thanks for helping me crizzis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your trigger Function like below:

```
-- Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_numlending() 
RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$ 
declare counter int;
BEGIN 
select count(*) into counter from lending where id_person =new.id_person;
IF( counter>=2  ) THEN 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR'; 
END IF; 
RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql; 


-- Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER  
trg_check_num_lending  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON 
lending FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_numlending();
```