# Conditional insert after an update in a transaction

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres 'update' query in my business flow and a requirement from a stakeholder to produce some more visible bookkeeping when the update is successful, in the form of "insert a line in this other table" (...let's not debate the reasons/wisdom behind this requirement).

I am currently implementing a composition of queries in application code:
`update` -> `async returns to server` -> `was the count > 0` -> `insert` -> `ok/ error handle + retry`.

Since the above is not the most efficient (2 trips to the database, potential network issues, error handling + retries involved), can it potentially be issued as a single transaction?
(The issue here being that an update of 0 rows is not an error, which further complicates things).

```
pseudo-code
BEGIN;
UPDATE ....;
IF (update_count > 0) THEN
  INSERT ...;
  COMMIT;
ELSE
  ROLLBACK or RAISE;
```

I am not particularly familiar with `CASE`, `WITH count AS (UPDATE)` or `RAISE`, to be able to compose the `SQL` I need, assuming a solution like the one I am describing is even workable?

Comment: This can be achieved using triggers or using functions. if you post the schema for both table with desired insert then we will be able to help you. Try This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235703/create-a-trigger-function-in-postgres-that-doesnt-let-you-have-two-entries-with/62235922#62235922)

Comment: Thanks @AkhileshMishra, I am more on a journey to try and figure it out myself, and to understand how to best go about doing something like this in PG. The schema can be trivial like table A has an integer and table B a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a `RETURNING` clause that returns rows affected by an `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.  Couple this with CTEs, and you can accomplish your objective in a single instruction:

```
begin;

with do_update as (
  update some_table
     set a = 1, b = 2, c =3
   where id = 999
  returning *
)
insert into audit_table
 (affected_table, updated_at, update_user)
select distinct 'some_table', now(), current_user
  from do_update
;

commit;
```

The `INSERT` statement has access to the results of the `UPDATE` through the CTE name `do_update`.  If no rows were updated, then nothing gets inserted into `audit_table`.  If one or more rows are updated, then the `DISTINCT` causes a single row to be inserted into `audit_table`.

Comment: Simple and easily testable, thanks. I think that this way there is no need to go anywhere near RAISE statements too.